# How to disable menu items in desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, disabled-control

I created a menu in the menu bar in which I'd like to create a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` to set a condition for highlighting remaining menu items.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
if login(true)
    then highlight remaining menuitems
else
    un-highlight the menuitems
```

Comment: What do you mean if login(true)?

Comment: i create the userlogin menuitem... -->on click that menuitem then the login page open---->then userlogin its account(by putting there userid & password)--->when login successfully then further menuitems highlight otherwies un-highlight menuitems..

Answer (score 5):

I think for highlighting you mean enable/disable a JMenuItem. That's possible.

Use setEnabled:

```
JMenuItem item;
item.setEnabled(false); //to disable
```

Like suggested by kleopatra, the best way of doing that is to implement your own action for each JMenuItem, and let your action to enable/disable the button accordingly to the state:

For example:

```
public class AMenuAction extends AbstractAction {

      @override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //implement your action behavior here
      }

}
```

Then construct your JMenuItem with such action:

```
AMenuAction afterLoginAction = new AMenuAction();
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(afterLoginAction );
```

When the user logged in/out call setEnabled method on the desired actions.

```
void Login()
{
    afterLoginAction.setEnabled(true); 
}
```

Comment: that's an invalid implementation of Action: it must fire a property change it its enabled property ... well ... changed :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: but I'm extending AbstractAction. Shouldn't be the default behavior already provided by AbstractAction.setEnable() method?

Comment: @kleopatra: could you explain me which is the right way to go? I don't know it.

Comment: DO. NOT. OVERRIDE. ISENABLED. Instead, call setEnabled after login was successful. Sorry for shouting, but I don't understand how you can't see the difference ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for shouting :). This way I think to have fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Enabling and disabling menu items is done in the same way as for any other `JComponent` by using the [`setEnabled( boolean )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) method

Comment: while true, it's not the best to do in this context :-) Instead, use actions that are enable/disabled depending on application state (@Heisenbug and Roman C as well)

Comment: @kleopatra fully agree on the use of the `Action` for the enabled state. Still hoping those guys at Oracle would add the same mechanism for visibility which would easily allow to create a context-sensitive pop-up menu which only shows the relevant actions, and not a bunch of disabled actions

Answer (score 2):

Create a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` as userlogin menu item

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
```

then

add action listener to it

```
  //unhighlite other menu items before login
  jMenuFileOpen.setEnabled(false);
  //...
  jCheckBoxMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (login(true)){
        jCheckBoxMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        //highlite other menu items
        jMenuFileOpen.setEnabled(true);
        //...
      } else {
        jCheckBoxMenuItem.setSelected(false);
        //unhighlite other menu items
        jMenuFileOpen.setEnabled(false);
        //...
      }
    }
  });
```

once `login(true)` is successful the checkbox is checked on menu and other menu items are enabled.

Comment: @kleopatra this is not a homework and using actions is out of topic.

Comment: ehh .. don't understand: _not a homework_? Only if it _were_ a homework not allowing the use of Action your answer would be correct :-)

Comment: I allow to use Action as much as OP wants but he didn't mention about it. I got already very fun with this question/answer activities. Something that is no true anyway is true or not nobody know.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to look at what the OP is trying to achieve, rather than what they say they want to do.  Best practices are always relevant.

Comment: Who limits him to tell us what OP is trying to achieve? If OP don't know it how could we help?